# List displaying different option based on chosen value

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following js and html code to display the lists. 
MAIN PROBLEM is that when the **sub-categories & categories** become to many, the categories change but the sub-categries are **not displaying** from a certain cagory going downwards. **Problem is on desktop/laptops**. Working correctly on mobile device. Am not god at javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#vehicle').on('change', function() {
        var vehileType = $('#vehicle').val();

        $('#vehicle-type option').hide();
        $('#vehicle-type option[vehicle="'+vehileType+'"]').show();        
    });
});
</script>

<select id="vehicle" required name="brand">
  <option value="">Select Make</option>
  <option value="ABT">ABT</option>
  <option value="AC">AC</option>
</select>

<select name="model" id="vehicle-type" class="form-control">

 <option vehicle="ABT" value="ABT">ABT</option>
 <option vehicle="ABT" value="ABT1">ABT1</option>

 <option vehicle="AC" value="AC">AC</option>
 <option vehicle="AC" value="AC1">AC1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code. Can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: am new at stackverflow. By fiddle to you mean a sample code or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I put vehicle options to custom variable `var vehicleTypeOptions = $('#vehicle-type option[vehicle="' + vehileType + '"]');`

Then after show I add this `$('#vehicle-type').val(vehicleTypeOptions.first().val());` so it will set the value of first vehicle type option

I also put `.trigger('change')` for a `#vehicle` so it will set vehicle types by the vehicle make so you don't have to manually set one option

Here is a working demo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#vehicle').on('change', function() {
        var vehileType = $('#vehicle').val();
        var vehicleTypeOptions = $('#vehicle-type option[vehicle="' + vehileType + '"]');
        
        $('#vehicle-type option').not(vehicleTypeOptions).hide();
        vehicleTypeOptions.show();   
        $('#vehicle-type').val(
         vehicleTypeOptions.first().val()
        );
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="vehicle" required name="brand">
  <option value="">Select Make</option>
  <option value="ABT">ABT</option>
  <option value="AC">AC</option>
</select>

<select name="model" id="vehicle-type" class="form-control">

 <option vehicle="ABT" value="ABT">ABT</option>
 <option vehicle="ABT" value="ABT1">ABT1</option>

 <option vehicle="AC" value="AC">AC</option>
 <option vehicle="AC" value="AC1">AC1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks its working correctly. But the categories that were not displaying there sub-categories are displaying, list that switches 1 sub-category after the other. Is there another way that will display the sub categories as a dropdown instead of the switching one?

Comment: There is always a way :) I found this fiddle on the internet http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/YVMzt/6/ which you can use, he is using same logic as you but with `class` instead of `vehicle`.

Comment: heey thanks again. I have gone through this fiddle but am getting lost since am not a guru in js. Could you please help me modify the fiddle t suit my case?? @debute

Comment: Sure, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/7x3rbhdp/ If you don't want to default see all optins, set "Select Make"'s value to `0` or something.

Comment: Thanks so much. It has perfectly worked out for me. @debute

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. If my answer helped you to solve your problem, you should mark my answer as "accepted".